# Provide message level web security to JAX-WS web service

Tags: web-services, soap, websphere, jax-ws, ws-security

I want to provide message level security to JAX-WS web service. We have already installed certificates,so transport level security is already there. 
Now we want to provide message level security. We are sending username and password in the soap header , as the web service will be used by different users. and based on username and password we need to provide relevant details for that user.

We are using IBM WebSphere and RAD for the development.
Could someone please suggest what could be the easiest way to provide message level security with minimal configuration?

Comment: This developerWorks article discusses how to configure and apply a policy set for WebSphere-provided message level security.  It's lengthy, but goes over the most extensive level of message security: confidentiality via encryption.  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/tutorials/0905_griffith/

Answer (score 0):

So here is the post that the reviewers think will be better.  Maybe it is, maybe it isn't:

Here are the get-right-down-to-it steps for configuring a UsernameToken for a JAX-WS application in WebSphere.

Since you are using RAD and applying policy/bindings with the admin console, be sure that you do not have 'use resources in workspace' turned on in your RAD server config. If you do, turn it off, then reinstall (not just redeploy) your apps.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/twbs_stand_alone_security_token.html

**Configuring a policy set and bindings for a stand-alone security token (UsernameToken or LTPA Token)**

You can secure web services by configuring the message-level WS-Security policy set and bindings for a stand-alone security token that is either a Lightweight Third Party Authentication (LTPA) token or a Username token.
Before you begin

This task assumes that the service provider and client that you are configuring are in the JaxWSServicesSamples application. See the documentation on accessing samples to learn how to obtain and install this application. Specify the following trace specification on your server to enable you to debug any future configuration problems that might occur.

*=info:com.ibm.wsspi.wssecurity.*=all:com.ibm.ws.webservices.wssecurity.*=all: 
com.ibm.ws.wssecurity.*=all: com.ibm.xml.soapsec.*=all: com.ibm.ws.webservices.trace.*=all: 
com.ibm.ws.websvcs.trace.*=all:com.ibm.ws.wssecurity.platform.audit.*=off:

If LTPA tokens are used, you must enable the application security on the application servers that are used for both the client and the service.
About this task

This topic describes how to configure a WS-Security policy set and provider bindings for a Username token or an LTPA token. For simplicity, this procedure demonstrates how to remove the timestamp, digital signature, and encryption attributes from the policy; however, you might want to include these attributes in your final configuration. To learn more, see the documentation on configuring a policy set and bindings for Asymmetric XML digital signature or XML encryption with client and provider application specific bindings.

In this task, default provider general bindings are used for the provider application to consume the tokens. If a caller configuration is required, an application-specific binding will be added for the provider.

Procedure

```
Create the custom policy set.
    In the administrative console, click Services > Policy sets > Application Policy sets.
    Click New.
    Specify Name = OneTokenPolicy.
    Click Apply.
    Under Policies, click Add > WS-Security.
Edit the custom policy set
    Remove digital signature, encryption, and timestamp.
        In the administrative console, clickWS-Security > Main Policy.
        Deselect Message level protection.
        Click Apply.
    Add the UsernameToken or LTPA token.
        Under Policy details, click Request token policies.
        Select Add Token Type.
        If you want to use a UsernameToken, select UserName. If you want to use an LTPA token, select LTPA.

        Token name=myToken.
        Click OK.
Configure the client to use the OneTokenPolicy policy set.
    In the administrative console, click Applications > Application types > WebSphere enterprise applications > JaxWSServicesSamples > Service client policy sets and bindings.
    Select the web services client resource.
    Click Attach Policy Set.
    Select OneTokenPolicy .
Create a custom binding for the client.
    Select the web services resource again.
    Click Assign Binding.
    Click New Application Specific Binding to create an application-specific binding
    Specify the bindings configuration name. name: oneTokenClientBinding
    Click Add > WS-Security
    If the Main Message Security Policy Bindings' panel does not display, select WS-Security.
Edit the custom binding for the client.
    Edit the identity token generator to send the identity username.
        Click request:myToken.
        Click Apply.
        Click Callback handler. User name=(yourUserid) Password=(yourPassword)
    Avoid trouble Avoid trouble: This is a userid/password that is valid on the user registry on the provider's system. If you are using LTPA tokens, the userid/password must be valid on both the consumer and provider registries.
    (Optional) If configuring a UsernameToken, add the following WS-Security custom properties:

    *com.ibm.wsspi.wssecurity.token.username.addNonce=true
    *com.ibm.wsspi.wssecurity.token.username.addTimestamp=true

    These custom properties are added because they are specified on the UsernameToken consumer default general bindings. If we do not specify those properties here, you will either need to remove those properties from the default provider general bindings or create application-specific bindings for the provider that does not include those properties.
    Click OK.
    Click Save
Configure the provider to use the OneTokenPolicy policy set.
    In the administrative console, click Applications > Application types > WebSphere enterprise applications > JaxWSServicesSamples > Service provider policy sets and bindings
    Select the web services provider resource (OneTokenPolicy)
    Click Attach Policy Set.
    Select OneTokenPolicy
    Note: Since no bindings are attached to the provider application, it will use the default provider general bindings for the token consumers.
(Optional) If you want to create a Caller configuration for the provider, create custom bindings for the provider.
    Select the web services provider resource again.
    Click Assign Binding
    Click New Application Specific Binding to create an application-specific binding
    Specify Bindings configuration name:oneTokenProvBinding
    Click Add > WS-Security
    If the Main Message Security Policy Bindings' Panel does not display, select WS-Security
(Optional) If a Caller configuration will be created, edit the custom bindings for the provider.
    Click Caller > New. Name: myCaller.
        If using a UsernameToken, enter the following:
            Caller identity local name: [leave blank]
        If using an LTPA token, enter the following:
            Caller identity local name: LTPAv2
            Caller identity local URI: http://www.ibm.com/websphere/appserver/tokentype
    Click OK.
Click Save to save your configuration changes.
Restart the client provider.
    Stop the client and the provider
    Restart the client and the provider
Test the Service.
    Point your web browser at the JaxWSServicesSamples: http://localhost:9080/wssamplesei/demo
    Avoid trouble Avoid trouble: Make sure you provide the correct hostname and port if your profile is not on the same machine or the port is not 9080.
    Select Message Type Synchronous Echo
    Make sure Use SOAP 1.2 is not selected
    Enter a message and click Send Message. The sample application should reply with JAXWS==>Message.
```

Results

The JaxWSServicesSamples web services application is configured to generate and consume a UsernameToken or LTPA token in the request message.

Answer (score -1):

Here are the get-right-down-to-it steps for configuring a UsernameToken for a JAX-WS application in WebSphere:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/twbs_stand_alone_security_token.html

Since you are using RAD and applying policy/bindings with the admin console, be sure that you do not have 'use resources in workspace' turned on in your RAD server config.  If you do, turn it off, then reinstall (not just redeploy) your apps.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10454891)

Comment: This is a link into the WebSphere product documentation which, although the link itself won't change, the content on the page will change if there is are any errors discovered on it, but the content in this post WILL NOT change if a modification was made to that page.  The OP is basically saying "I don't know how to configure a UsernameToken for WebSphere, please tell me how".  Well, 'how' is 75 steps. Pretty much all 75 steps.  If you read the link, you'll see that there is no summary that would be helpful to the user unless they were familiar with policy configuration, which the OP is not.

Comment: If the OP had asked: "I tried to configure this, but when I run it, I get this bad response", then I'd say how to go about fixing it.  But "I haven't done anything yet, tell me how to do it" really deserves a link to the task-oriented docs, yes?  That link will probably live longer that I'm alive.